# Can't Update environment Variable in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm using C# and Azure Functions. I need to refresh a twitter token every 2 hours. I have the token and the refresh token stored as environment variables.

When I try to refresh them and set them by using this code:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TwitterBearerToken", 
                                   twitterTokens.accessToken, 
                                   EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: how do you intend to read that? the same process? another one?

Comment: Well it's the same function running with a time trigger. So the Goal is to refresh the key get a new token store it in the environment variables then use it for the upcoming runs until it expires

Comment: how are those "upcoming runs" executed?

Comment: Instead of storing refresh token in environment variable, store it in Keyvault, or a database.

Comment: @DanielA.White They are executed by a time trigger

Comment: As per @AnandSowmithiran's comment, you should be using KeyVault.  Store it there so it can be referenced from elsewhere and also for security reasons.  If you still want to use envionment variables then you'll need to use the Azure Management SDK that allows you to update properties of a function app.

Answer (score 0):

You should store refresh token securely in `Azure KeyVault`, that is the recommended approach. If you already database operations in your app, you could store in one of your config tables, but it will be adding latency and overhead when compared to reading from Keyvault.

Refer this Microsoft `doc` for refresh tokens [scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/secrets/secure-refresh-tokens).